# LINQ to Entities DateTime is inconsistent

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, linq-to-entities

I have the following C# code that creates a `DateTime`, enters it into a table, and then queries that table:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

DateTest newRecord = new DateTest {
    dateColumn = date
};

db.DateTest.AddObject(newRecord);
db.SaveChanges();

IQueryable<DateTest> records =
    from d in db.DateTest
    select d;
```

If I break the code at this point, and take a look at the objects in the debugger, I get this for the `date` object:

```
Date    {11/22/2011 12:00:00 AM}    System.DateTime
Day 22  int
DayOfWeek   Tuesday System.DayOfWeek
DayOfYear   326 int
Hour    8   int
Kind    Local   System.DateTimeKind
Millisecond 345 int
Minute  59  int
Month   11  int
Second  33  int
Ticks   634575491733450602  long
TimeOfDay   {08:59:33.3450602}  System.TimeSpan
Year    2011    int
```

And I get this for the record retrieved from the table:

```
Date    {11/22/2011 12:00:00 AM}    System.DateTime
Day 22  int
DayOfWeek   Tuesday System.DayOfWeek
DayOfYear   326 int
Hour    8   int
Kind    Unspecified System.DateTimeKind
Millisecond 347 int
Minute  59  int
Month   11  int
Second  33  int
Ticks   634575491733470000  long
TimeOfDay   {08:59:33.3470000}  System.TimeSpan
Year    2011    int
```

As you can see, they're off by a couple milliseconds.

Can anyone explain why this is, and how I can fix it?  I need to be able to query for records exactly matching a `DateTime` object in memory, but this behaviour is causing my queries to come up empty handed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The resolution of the `DateTime` field in SQL Server is different from the one of the `DateTime` .NET class.

From MSDN - [datetime (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx):

> Accuracy: Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

So, in your case, the milliseconds get rounded up to the `.007`, giving `.3470000` instead of `.3450602`.

The [`DateTime2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) SQL Server datatype has a resolution of 100 nano seconds, like .NET, so may be a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is because you are using a `DateTime` column in the database. It does not have the same precision as the `DateTime` type in .NET. Try using column type `DateTime2` in the database instead.

Comment: Thanks, DateTime2 solved it.  I used a precision of DateTime2(7) - will that be reliably equivalent to the .NET DateTime?

Comment: @Eric Yes, (default is 7 by the way) then both will have an accuracy of 100 nanoseconds.